# Why isn't my font awesome icon background loading?

Tags: html, css

I'm relatatively new to website deisgn, and I'm learning CSS at the moment. I'm having this issue where by background for the other 2 icons have loaded, but the 2nd one doesn't.

```css
.bg-instagram {
  padding: 7px 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 30% 107%, #fdf497 0%, #fdf497 5%, #fd5949 45%, #d6249f 60%, #285AEB 90%);
}

.bg-whatsapp {
  padding: 7px 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
}

.bg-facebook {
  padding: 7px 13px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #3b5998;
}
```

```html
<div class="container shadow rounded-pill bg-white py-5">
  <p>
    <a class="fa-icon mx-4" href="#" title="">
      <i class="fa fa-instagram fa-2x text-white bg-instagram"></i>
    </a>
    <a class="fa-icon mx-4" href="#" title="">
      <i class="fa fa-whatsapp fa-2x text-dark bg-whatsapp"></i>
    </a>
    <a class="fa-icon mx-4" href="#" title="">
      <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x text-white bg-facebook"></i>
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
```

I hope someone can help me spot any glaring issues I may have with my code. Thanks!

Comment: background is working , where is the problem

Comment: Hi, I realised that it's because I had to do a hard refresh on the browser for it to load the changes. Thanks

Comment: @taubar can you please create an answer for that solution instead of a comment? that way others can see your question is answered while looking at the question lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry to leave the question hanging, I realised it wasn’t loading because I had to hard refresh the browser for it to load the css file!

Answer (score 1):

### Check this, font awesome is working. I think you forget to use font awesome CDN.

> No icon i found by this name in font awesome .fa-icon class.

```css
.bg-instagram {
  padding: 7px 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 30% 107%, #fdf497 0%, #fdf497 5%, #fd5949 45%, #d6249f 60%, #285AEB 90%);
}

.bg-whatsapp {
  padding: 7px 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
}

.bg-facebook {
  padding: 7px 13px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #3b5998;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Font Awesome Icons</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container shadow rounded-pill bg-white py-5">
  <p>your code</p>
    <a class="fa-icon mx-4" href="#" title="">
      <i class="fa fa-instagram fa-2x text-white bg-instagram"></i>
    </a>
    <a class="fa-icon mx-4" href="#" title="">
      <i class="fa fa-whatsapp fa-2x text-dark bg-whatsapp"></i>
    </a>
    <a class="fa-icon mx-4" href="#" title="">
      <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x text-white bg-facebook"></i>
    </a>
  <br /><br />
   <p>my different  code</p>
    <i class="fa fa-facebook-official" aria-hidden="true" style="background-color:blue; font-size:40px;"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true" style=" background: radial-gradient(circle at 30% 107%, #fdf497 0%, #fdf497 5%, #fd5949 45%, #d6249f 60%, #285AEB 90%); font-size:40px;"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-whatsapp" aria-hidden="true" style="background-color:green; font-size:40px;"></i>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```